# Alternative display name for facets in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

I'm using RavenDB for faceted search. Everything is working very well, but when I retrieve facets for my search results, those facets are named the same as the properties they represent on the document.

Are there anything built in, so that I can specify my own display names for facets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the names before you show them to the client

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that - just wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing something built in.